# How to read multple text files in R

Tags: r

I have multiple tab separated two columns files as follows:

```
[enter code here][1]
```

I want to merge them like the following:

```
[enter code here][1]
```

rownames may have missing in some cases. I have tried in many ways but failed to get the expected result. Maybe I am missing something. Any help?

```
fls=list.files('/Users/mzillur/geo/data/E-GEOD-64573/')
ids <- read.table(fls[1], header=FALSE, sep="\t")[,1]
d1=do.call(cbind,lapply(fls,function(fn)read.table(fn,header=FALSE, sep="\t")[,2]))
d2=cbind(ids,d1)
```

Any help about this?
Best Regards
Zillur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `? map_dfc`

```
library(purrr)

map_dfc(fls, read.table, header = FALSE, sep = "\t")
```

Comment: Thank you. It works but I am getting rownames for each column, which I don't want. I need only one column of rownames for all the columns.

Comment: Ahh! got it. I had to put row.names=1, then manually add the rownames from a list. Is it the right way? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes that is fine. If the answer is correct, click the check symbol to accept it and close it.